# Compare 2 HashMaps in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have the following method, I would like to compare between the 2 HashMap
: map1 and map2.

every HashMap has:

`key: string.`

```
value: ArrayList<String>
```

What I am trying to do is to check if both HashMaps are equal

```
    public boolean compareT(HashMap map1, HashMap map2) {

        Iterator entriesH = map1.entrySet().iterator();
        Iterator entriesE = map2.entrySet().iterator();

        if (map1.size() == map2.size()) {
            while (entriesE.hasNext() && entriesH.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry eEntry = (Map.Entry) entriesE.next();
                Map.Entry hEntry = (Map.Entry) entriesH.next();
            }
        }
}
```

**EDIT**

The following maps should return TRUE:

```
map1: 
key: key1, value: v1, v6, v3, v2 
key: key2, value: b1, b6, b2, b7


map2:  
key: key1, value: v6, v3, v2, v1  
key: key2, value: b6, b1, b7, b2
```

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: There is no guarantee at all that the two maps will return the entries in the same order, even if all the keys/values are identical.

Comment: `map1.equals(map2)` will check that the two maps contain the same keys mapped to the same values, regardless of order, [as specified by `Map::equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)

Comment: Should i order the values of every key before i compare them?

Comment: @user9524367 In this specific case that would work, but in general you have no way of knowing whether the keys are comparable. What is wrong with the `equals()` method of `HashMap`? Is this an exercise?

Comment: If you use a `Set<>` for the values, it'd work. Sets are order independent.

Comment: You can use Reflections.asserts(...) or if(EqualsBuilder.reflectionEquals(expected,actual)) == true)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the size is the same for both maps, which you do
2. Check that all the keys are the same for both maps, map1.equals(map2)
3. If all the keys are the same, then start grabbing one key at a time and compare the arraylists.

If you never get map1.get(key).get(index) != map2.get(key).get(index) then you can be sure that the maps are the same.

Pseudo Code

```
if(map1.size == map2.size && map1.equals(map2))
    //in here means the keys are the same
    allkeys = map1's keys
    for (string key : allKeys)
        //now we need to loop through the arraylists
        map1Arraylist = map1.get(key)
        map2Arraylist = map2.get(key)
        //check the sizes are the same if not return false right away
        if(map1Arraylist.size != map2Arraylist.size) return false;
        //if we got to here we now must check each index is the same
        for(index = 0; index < map1Arraylist.size; index++)
            //if a single index of the arraylists don't match up we return false
            if(map1Arraylist.get(index) != map2Arraylist.get(index))
                return false;

    //if we get out of all the above logic then we have the same maps
    return true;
else return false;
```

Comment: this Pseudo code should be pretty self explanatory and you can easily implement it into your existing compare method @user9524367

Answer (score 1):

> Should i order the values of every key before i compare them?

Your values are `ArrayList` objects.  ArrayLists (or any other `List` implementation) are only considered to be equal if they have the same entries *in the same order*.

Maybe you could use some kind of `java.util.Set` instead.

Comment: There's no `ArrayList` in the question but a `Set` should do it.